# How do I render pages with dynamic content from a json feed

Tags: templating, craft3, modules

I am building a module to show a job/vacancy-list and the detailpage of a job, the data is fetched from a remote json feed.

Currently I have the following routes to a controller in my module

```
return [
  'job' => 'job-offers-module/job/process',
  'job/detail' => 'job-offers-module/job/detail',
];
```

And loading twig templates eg.

```
namespace modules\joboffersmodule\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;
use craft\web\View;

class JobController extends Controller
{
  protected $allowAnonymous = true;

  public function actionProcess(){
    return \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('joblist');
  }
  public function actionDetail(){
    return \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('jobdetail');
  }
}
```

But I keep getting an error that the *entry can not be found*... Do I need to register the paths in the module as a handle?

How can I load an entry from my within the module and pass it to the templates?

Comment: Does not answer your question, but you could consider to use feed me pro for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch an entry from your module and pass it to a template you can do:

```
$entry = \craft\elements\Entry::find()->one();
return \Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('path/to/template', ['entry' => $entry]);
```

Then in your template, you will have access to an `entry` variable.